Ingress-nginx controller external ip is in pending state
I’ve manually set up a Kubernetes cluster on Azure VMs because Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) does not support RHEL. All my application services are configured with portType: ClusterIP. Now, when I attempt to create the ingress-nginx controller, the service's external IP status remains in a pending state indefinitely.
Here’s a steps I’ve tried:

Custom Kubernetes Cluster : I manually created a Kubernetes cluster, which led to difficulties in having the Ingress controller automatically assign a public/external IP. As a result, I manually created a public IP.
Azure Load Balance: I manually set up an Azure Load Balancer and assigned the public IP to it.
NGINXaaS : I attempted to use NGINX as a service (NGINXaaS) for load balancing. However, since it’s an external load balancer, it was unable to route traffic to the cluster’s internal ClusterIP services.
MetalLB : I also tried configuring MetalLB to handle the load balancing but was unsuccessful.

Expectation:
ingress-nginx controller get assigned with externalIP

Before this question is inevitably closed, I will give you a pointer what to look next. Basically you need "azure cloud controller manager" configured and running in your cluster. this will make service of type loadbalanacer automatically create an azure load balancer for you. Check https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cloud-provider-azure
